# Error Executing Script when building with the Grails Jenkins plugin?

Tags: grails, groovy, jenkins

When trying to do a compile of a simple Grails 2.1 application with Jenkins I am getting a failure with the for the following reason:

> Error Error executing script Compile: startup failed:
>   /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/EskridgeBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy.class (No such file or directory)

Further up the chain I get:

> Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"

Which may or may not be related.

I can build the same project from the command line on the same box successfully.

### Version Info

- Grails command line version is `Grails version: 2.1.1`.
- Jenkins version is `1.492`
- Grails Jenkins plugin version is `1.6.3`

### Full console output:

> Started by user anonymous Building in workspace
>   /srv/jenkins/jobs/MyBudget-BUILD/workspace [workspace] $ hg showconfig
>   paths.default [workspace] $ hg pull --rev default [workspace] $ hg
>   update --clean --rev default 0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files
>   removed, 0 files unresolved [workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template
>   {node} [workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template {rev} [workspace] $ hg
>   log --rev ac19aee9ab6db38a6b42c72f41d0bc0fa0c59511 [workspace] $ hg
>   log --template "{desc|xmlescape}{file_adds|stringify|xmlescape}{file_dels|stringify|xmlescape}{files|stringify|xmlescape}{parents}\n"
>   --rev default:0 --follow --prune ac19aee9ab6db38a6b42c72f41d0bc0fa0c59511 [workspace] $ grails
>   -Dgrails.work.dir=/tmp/jenkins-grails compile --non-interactive Arguments:  -Dgrails.work.dir=/tmp/jenkins-grails compile
>   --non-interactive JAVA_OPTS: -server -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager  GRAILS_OPTS: -server -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:48)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:185)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.(LogManager.java:175)    at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:327)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.(DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.java:33)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:84)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:61)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.(GroovySystem.java:29)  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.(InvokerHelper.java:49)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.(Closure.java:224)     at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.(Closure.java:241)  at
>   groovy.lang.Closure$1.(Closure.java:208)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.(Closure.java:208)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.(GrailsScriptRunner.java:84)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
>
> | Loading Grails 2.1.1 | Configuring classpath | Error Error executing
>   script Compile: startup failed:
>   /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure1.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> /tmp/jenkins-grails/projects/MyBudget/scriptCache/_GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure5.class
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> 10 errors  (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) Build step 'Build
>   With Grails' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Comment: kind of a dummy-check: is `/tmp/jenkins-grails/` a path the Jenkins process has permissions to fiddle with?  and/or: when you run outside of Jenkins successfully, do you set the grails work directory in the same way?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  *headdesk*  The Mercurial plugin I'm using copies the files under the same permissions as the repository.  @BrianHenry Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `/tmp/jenkins-grails/` is a path that the Jenkins process has permissions to fiddle with.  (and/or: when you run outside of Jenkins successfully, set the grails work directory in the same way, if you don't currently, to verify).